# access apache2 on custom port, without specifying the port in the url

Tags: mysql, apache, dns, phpmyadmin, portforwarding

I have a cloud server where I host bitwarden myself. Since not all resources are needed I have now migrated my mysql database to the server. Since bitwarden uses port 80 and 443 I used other ports for apache2 (e.g. 1080 and 1443).

So far everything works, but now I have to specify the port in the URL to reach `apache2/phpmyadmin`.

I access Bitwarden at: `key.example.com`

I can access phpmyadmin at: `example.com:1080/phpmyadmin`

I want to access phpmyadmin at: `example.com/phpmyadmin`

I'm sure the solution to this is common and there are already several posts about it, however I couldn't manage to tell google properly what exactly I want to achieve.

I think i have to forward `example.com:1080/phpmyadmin` to `example.com:1080/phpmyadmin` in my dns settings and then do some forwarding in apache back to `example.com:1080/phpmyadmin`.

I tried some settings to add a reverse proxy in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

like that:

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com:1080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com/
```

Didn't work.

A short tutorial or a link to a post that could help me would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `ProxyPassReverse` without port number?

Comment: look at phpinfo if you ave loaded the modules mod_proxy mod_proxy_http in apache

Comment: I would use RewriteCond and RewriteRule with option [P] to proxy phpmyadmin on port 80 to phpmyadmin on port 1080.  How you currently do it, you are redirecting everything (/) to port 1080.  Or be more specific in your ProxyPass configuration, look at examples in the documentation.